# Embedding YouTube Video in a SharePoint 2010 List?

Tags: 2010, list

First, thank you in advance for any help anyone is able to give.

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site that needs the ability to embed YouTube videos in the rich text field of a list item, is there anyway to do it, and if so, how?

Currently, when my users copy & paste in code to embed a video from YouTube, Sharepoint automatically modifies it, stripping out the  and  tags and everything in between.

I need a way to either stop it from modifying the code OR to allow  and/or  tags.  Either option would be fine since the users on this site are sufficiently skilled & trustworthy to allow them broader options to make the list accept any code.

I dearly hope someone can help!

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this. However, would it be acceptable to use another field? In this field the user would paste the URL of the youtube video, and on the page where you would like to embed it, you could add javascript to create an iframe with the appropriate attributes.

Comment: Try using Media Webpart (from Media and Content Category).

Answer (score 4):

Saving `IFrame` element (embed code for YouTube by default) in [Rich text fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.richtextfield.aspx) is not allowed  in SharePoint 2010

For storing YouTube video content in SharePoint List the following solutions could be used:

### Store embedded video properties

Using this approach embed code properties are stored in List Item as shown on picture below.
[image]
YouTube  Video player is rendered in List View using [Computed Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcomputed.aspx)

Please follow [this post](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint/) for more details

### Store embed code in text field

Field of [Note type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.notefield.aspx) is used for storing embed code as shown on picture below. 
[image]

To render YouTube video player in List a customized List View is used

Please follow [this post](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint-part-two-posting-embedded-code-support-for-different-video-providers-preview-view/) for more details

### Result

List View with support to play YouTube video content

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Workaround using jquery:

1) add this tag to the SP field

```
<div class="myCompany_iframe" style="visibility: hidden">width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Basc-0edkhw?list=sasd" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</div>
```

2) Add this script to the page/master page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$( ".myCompany_iframe" ).each(function() {
$(this).html("<iframe " +  $(this).html() + "></iframe>").css("visibility","visible");
});

});</script>
```

Mirco

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound clumsy but I have had this work in the past...

1. Edit your Rich Content
2. Insert a Content Editor Web Part into the Rich    Content
3. Edit the content of the new web part
4. Add the YouTube code to    the source view of the CEWP
5. Save your changes

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: How do you insert a web part into a Rich Text field? I do not see an option to do so in the ribbon.

Comment: On my pages, if I simply click anywhere in the text of the Rich Content box, the option appears on the `Insert` submenu of the `Editing Tools` tab.  The Rich Content Editor has about 3 different modes that it can operate under and you might be in one of the lower-functionality modes which might not allow this.

Comment: Dave, is it at all possible you are referring to the RTE of a publishging page, and not the RTE of a multi-line text field? If not, where would I change the field to having this functionality? It is already set to "Enhanced rich text". Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and thank you VERY much for responding.

First,  The field type is a Multiple Lines of Text column. 

Second, it is already set to Enhanced Rich Text Mode.

Third, I don't have the option to insert a Content Editor Web Part into the Rich Content zone.  Sadly this one isn't a publising page, it's actually the view of a list item.

Comment: That may be the difference.  As I said, the same RTE operates in a number of different modes, some more restricted than others.  In the case I am referring to, the field type is "Publishing HTML".  FWIW, I just tested this using the IFRAME src provided by YouTube and it does indeed still work ... for this particular type of field anyway.

Comment: And you are able to do this in an item in a list?  

Can you share the list settings that you have, especially on the column that that you're able to insert the <iframe> into?  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to be limited to the Publishing HTML field types in the Publishing /Pages/ library.  So it is possible, just not in a way that helps you :(  You might want to look into using a Data View Web Part or even customizing the DispForm.aspx page in Designer, depending on how and where you want the embedded video to appear.